# How is augmented major seventh chord functioning? (Gadd9/B Ebmaj7#5/B Cadd9)

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions, jazz

[image: "Amazing Grace", rehearsal mark F, 3 measures]

In this excerpt from a gospel arrangement of Amazing Grace, how is the Ebmaj7#5/B chord functioning? Is it a version of a tritone sub, but we've just decided to make it augmented major seventh? Seems like it's a tritone sub but we keep the B and D harmony of the G chord and thus it becomes an aug maj 7th. Are there general rules for when to use augmented major sevenths, or a version of a 251 with them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually a very common chord progression, but disguised by the spelling.

The progression `G  G+  C` — or, more generally, `I  I+  IV` — is a frequent way to move chromatically from a `I` chord to a `IV` chord.

To see this, respell the Ebaug from `Eb  G  B` to `G  B  D#`. However, to call the chord Gaug(add12)/B would be very strange indeed,<sup>1</sup> and would suggest a different voicing of the chord. So the Ebmaj7(#5) makes more sense in terms of expressing how the chord should actually be played.

Here, though, is the underlying chord progression described above.

[image: I I+ IV progression in G major]

This core-level voice-leading can be seen in the "Amazing Grace" excerpt. The Eb (D#) proceeds to E; the B proceeds to C; and the G stays put.

[image: Voice-leading illustration]

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sub>G(b6)/B would be simpler; however, it's imperative (in this arrangement) that the D be the highest pitch, as it's the melody. The Ebmaj7(#5) and (more consistent with theory, but not useful in practice) G+(add12) names clarify that point.</sub>

Comment: G(b6)/B would be less strange, wouldn't it?

Comment: @user1079505 Absolutely. I've added a footnote in that regard.

Comment: Nice answer, I like the showing of the voice leading. As for your footnote there isn’t an easy name for that chord but as you know, no chord symbol is going to guarantee having a D on top. For that reason I like Eb+maj7/B because it at least somewhat implies the D over the Eb. An augmented major seventh chord is not really that strange or unusual, especially in jazz.